# How to find a string at a specific location with regex with java?

Tags: regex

How to find a string at a specific location with regex?

choryangStn_110_220114_one_0.sbm
choryangStn_110_220114_two_0.sbm
choryangStn_110_220114_three_0.sbm
I want to get one, two, three from

I wonder how this is possible.

best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `String#replaceAll` here:

```java
String filename = "choryangStn_110_220114_one_0.sbm";
String num = filename.replaceAll(".*_(\\w+)_\\d+\\.\\w+", "$1");
System.out.println(num);  // one
```